# Magento 1.9 - Error when calculating USPS shipping rates "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time"

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, usps

When checking out with USPS rates, I get the error: 
"Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time."

Shipping method is set to USPS with specific countries set to "United States", and the shipping address for the customer has a country and zip.

When I change it to flat rate shipping, things work well.

Can you give me some clues on how to fix this? 
-Thanks

...Just checked the logs and here is what I am seeing:

```
2017-10-04T16:58:26+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [request] => <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RateV4Request USERID="226FORTY3790"><Revision>2</Revision><Package ID="0"><Service>ALL</Service><ZipOrigination>91748</ZipOrigination><ZipDestination>36532</ZipDestination><Pounds>5</Pounds><Ounces>0</Ounces><Container>VARIABLE</Container><Size>REGULAR</Size><Machinable>true</Machinable></Package></RateV4Request>

    [result] => <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RateV4Response><Package ID="0"><ZipOrigination>91748</ZipOrigination><ZipDestination>36532</ZipDestination><Pounds>5</Pounds><Ounces>0</Ounces><Size>REGULAR</Size><Machinable>TRUE</Machinable><Zone>7</Zone><Postage CLASSID="3"><MailService>Priority Mail Express 2-Day&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#8482;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt;</MailService><Rate>59.45</Rate></Postage><Postage CLASSID="2"><MailService>Priority Mail Express 2-Day&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#8482;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt; Hold For Pickup</MailService><Rate>59.45</Rate></Postage><Postage CLASSID="13"><MailService>Priority Mail Express 2-Day&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#8482;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt; Flat Rate Envelope</MailService><Rate>23.75</Rate></Postage><Postage CLASSID="27"><MailService>Priority Mail Express 2-Day&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#8482;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt; Flat Rate Envelope Hold For Pickup</MailService><Rate>23.75</Rate></Postage><Postage CLASSID="30"><MailService>Priority Mail Express 2-Day&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#8482;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt; Legal Flat Rate Envelope</MailService><Rate>23.95</Rate></Postage><Postage CLASSID="31"><MailService>Priority Mail Express 2-Day&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#8482;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt; Legal Flat Rate Envelope Hold For Pickup</MailService><Rate>23.95</Rate></Postage><Postage CLASSID="62"><MailService>Priority Mail Express 2-Day&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#8482;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt; Padded Flat Rate Envelope</MailService><Rate>24.45</Rate></Postage><Postage CLASSID="63"><MailService>Priority Mail Express 2-Day&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#8482;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt; Padded Flat Rate Envelope Hold For Pickup</MailService><Rate>24.45</Rate></Postage><Postage CLASSID="1"><MailService>Priority Mail 2-Day&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#8482;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt;</MailService><Rate>20.65</Rate></Postage><Postage CLASSID="22"><MailService>Priority Mail 2-Day&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#8482;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt; Large Flat Rate Box</MailService><Rate>18.85</Rate></Postage><Postage CLASSID="17"><MailService>Priority Mail 2-Day&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#8482;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt; Medium Flat Rate Box</MailService><Rate>13.60</Rate></Postage><Postage CLASSID="28"><MailService>Priority Mail 2-Day&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#8482;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt; Small Flat Rate Box</MailService><Rate>7.15</Rate></Postage><Postage CLASSID="16"><MailService>Priority Mail 2-Day&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#8482;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt; Flat Rate Envelope</MailService><Rate>6.65</Rate></Postage><Postage CLASSID="44"><MailService>Priority Mail 2-Day&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#8482;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt; Legal Flat Rate Envelope</MailService><Rate>6.95</Rate></Postage><Postage CLASSID="29"><MailService>Priority Mail 2-Day&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#8482;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt; Padded Flat Rate Envelope</MailService><Rate>7.20</Rate></Postage><Postage CLASSID="38"><MailService>Priority Mail 2-Day&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#8482;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt; Gift Card Flat Rate Envelope</MailService><Rate>6.65</Rate></Postage><Postage CLASSID="42"><MailService>Priority Mail 2-Day&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#8482;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt; Small Flat Rate Envelope</MailService><Rate>6.65</Rate></Postage><Postage CLASSID="40"><MailService>Priority Mail 2-Day&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#8482;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt; Window Flat Rate Envelope</MailService><Rate>6.65</Rate></Postage><Postage CLASSID="4"><MailService>USPS Retail Ground&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#8482;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt;</MailService><Rate>19.00</Rate></Postage><Postage CLASSID="6"><MailService>Media Mail Parcel</MailService><Rate>4.59</Rate></Postage><Postage CLASSID="7"><MailService>Library Mail Parcel</MailService><Rate>4.38</Rate></Postage></Package></RateV4Response>
    [__pid] => 499474
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was something dumb ---> I actually did not have any Allowed Methods selected for USPS.  I was depending on the default setting.

Answer (score 0):

Did you patch your Magento recently? They made some changes regarding USPS recently. Check this out:

```
Follow this procedure to edit the Usps.php file to use the new shipping method name:

1) Navigate to app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Usps.php.

2) Search for the string First-Class Mail Parcel. This files by default contains two occurrences of this string.

3) Replace all the occurrences of First-Class Mail Parcel with First-Class Package Service - Retail.

4) Save your changes to Usps.php.

5) Flush the Magento cache.
```

Taken from: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/tech_bull_USPS-patch-Sept2017.html

Comment: How can i set the condition, USPS Media mail Parcel applicable for only selected category products, if any other products included in the cart the USPS media mail not eligible even the selected category products exits.